# Windows 2008 64bit permissions and Lotus Domino 8.5.x

Tags: windows-server-2008, ibm-domino

I have an application running on a Domino Server (8.5.3) on Windows 2008 64 bit O/S.

Since the recent upgrade to 2008, the agents with OLE integration to MS Word no longer run when the Domino Server runs as a service.  This does work when it's run as a standard application.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this is happening.

My immediate thought is Windows 2008 - so I have tried the following:

- turning off UAC
- changing the environment variable for the location of the temp (and tmp) directory to be c:\temp
- made sure that MS Word runs as administrator
- tested running MS Word in compatibility mode

The error occurs when the system is trying to edit the document.  This all works fine when Domino is running as a local application.

Does anyone have any other thoughts for what I can change?

A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to create a folder called “Desktop” in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile.

It sounds weird but give it a try.

I have blogged about it:
http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2011/04/excel-automation-on-windows-server-2008-x64.html

Comment: Beat me to it.  Also seems to be the accepted solution in the following social.msdn thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/innovateonoffice/thread/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91

Comment: Thanks Per - I will give that a try and let you know.  How you worked this out I will never know!

Comment: Well I never!  It worked!  This is honestly the most obscure thing I have come across for ages!  Thanks Per.  How  very strange...

Comment: My thought exactly when I found the solution: very strange! :-)